# AdminLTE 3 Showing active menu on Menu with dropdown

Tags: html, jquery, css, adminlte

If I select View Enquiry needs to be
For main li:liStaff_Enquiry like -- nav-item menu-is-opening menu-open

Particular a : aStaff_aViewEnquiry  -- nav-link active

``````````````````````````
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">

<li class="nav-item">
<a href="../Staff/Dashboard.aspx" class="nav-link">
<i class="nav-icon fas fa-home"></i>
<p>Dashboard</p>
</a>
</li>

<li class="nav-item" id="liStaff_Enquiry" runat="server">
<a href="#" class="nav-link">
<i class="nav-icon fas fa-expand"></i>
<p>
Enquiry
<i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
</p>
</a>
<ul class="nav nav-treeview">
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="../Enquiry/ViewEnquiry.aspx" class="nav-link" id="aStaff_aViewEnquiry" runat="server">
<i class="far fa-circle nav-icon text-cyan"></i>
<p>View Enquiry</p>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
</li> 
<li class="nav-item">
<a href="../Login_Down.aspx" class="nav-link">
<i class="nav-icon fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>
<p>Logout</p>
</a>
</li>

</ul>
`````````````````````````


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC2d8.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fALRN.png
``````````````````````````

Comment: Hey i just wanted to point out that the image is not working

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC2d8.png image url